# Simple arrow mayavi/tvtk in mlab weird behaviour (looks like a bug)

Tags: python, vtk, enthought, mayavi

I am trying to do a simple arrow in mlab to point to different areas on the graph. 
Consider this example:

```
fig = mlab.figure( bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
b=visual.Box(x=0, y=10, z=10)
visual.set_viewer(fig)
b=visual.Box(x=0, y=10, z=10)
b2=visual.Box(x=10,y=10,z=10, color=(0,0,1))
a=visual.Arrow(x=10,y=10,z=10, color=(1,0,0))
```

So in my mind the arrow should appear from the blue box, however it lives it's own misterious life and is located absolutely off. That is very strange that boxes are located and bound to the grid (so if I put b to x=10,y=10,z=10 the two boxes will be collocated), however the arrow is not. [image: This is what I see]  Is this a bug or a feature?

Update:

I was playing around trying to fix the above and found the behaviour of the arrow very weird. This is what I do (in `ipython` for interaction):

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.tools import visual
fig=mlab.figure( bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
visual.set_viewer(fig)
```

First put the box somewhere on canvas as a reference:

```
b=visual.Box(x=10,y=4,z=1)
```

Then I want an arrow sticking out of the box:

```
a=visual.Arrow(x=10,y=4,z=1)
```

Didn't work out (same as the first part of the question):

[image: Arrow_error]

Now, let's change length of the cone without reason

```
a.length_cone
```

returns

```
0.35
```

Let's change it

```
a.length_cone=0.5
```

Now the arrow is sticking out of the box as it should be
[image: Arrow_error]

Change length of the cone back to 0.35 to see if this changes the arrow back to wrong position

```
a.length_cone=0.35
```

No, the arrow stays in the box where it should be. This looks like a bug.

Comment: What package is `visual`?

Comment: `from tvtk.tools import visual`

Answer (score 3):

Playing around with arrow, I wrote the following function to generate an arrow from `x1,y1,z1` to `x2,y2,z2`

```
def Arrow_From_A_to_B(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2):
    ar1=visual.arrow(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1)
    ar1.length_cone=0.4

    arrow_length=np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2)
    ar1.actor.scale=[arrow_length, arrow_length, arrow_length]
    ar1.pos = ar1.pos/arrow_length
    ar1.axis = [x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1]
    return ar1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `ArrowSource` doesn't allow for arrows extending beyond a short distance.  It doesn't seem very useful at all.  mlab functions like `quiver3d` return glyphs based on `PolyDataSource` instead.

This will plot two boxes and an arrow between them.  I'm not sure if there's a simple way to do it with quiver3d which is definitely based off of PolyDataSource but may not have the same structure somehow.

```
b1=visual.Box()
b2=visual.Box(x=10)
v=mlab.pipeline.vectors(mlab.pipeline.vector_scatter(0,0,0,10,0,0)) #xyzuvw
v.glyph.glyph.clamping=False
```

Also, the behavior you encountered with `ArrowSource` doesn't seem like a bug, it's more like a minor feature that wasn't really developed.

Comment: That's a possible solution, thanks. However, I don't like how this arrow looks like. IS there a way of changing its looks (to something like the one in the question)

Comment: You can alter `v.glyph.glyph_source.glyph_source.glyph_type` but none of those choices result in a cone-tipped arrow.  But some of them will produce different-looking arrows.